# MOODLE: This quiz is notavailable

Tags: moodle

I installed Moodle on my system using xampp server, moodle is working properly, I am able to add users, create courses etc. But when I add a quiz and set the timing, the quiz will show:
"This quiz is not currently available"
The time and date is correct am using moodle 3.11

Answer (score 0):

Go to preference, under user account select edit profile
[image: profile]

Then go to time zone and change to the appropriate time zone

[image: time zone]

Refresh your browser